# Having issue with displaying processes in combobox

Tags: .net, vb.net, visual-studio-2010, process

In my application a user clicks a button then a form loads and in this form there is a combobox that generates a window process list and displays the window names.

It always works fine in visual studio, although when I launch a compiled version I always get this error "Process {0} not found.

I thought this meant it had no processes to read so I added some code to only display if the amount is greater than or equal to 1 and it didn't help.

Does anyone see my issue?

```
     Dim ProcessList() As Process = Process.GetProcesses
    If ProcessList.Count() >= 1 Then
        For I = 0 To UBound(ProcessList)
            If ProcessList(I).MainWindowTitle.ToString = "" = False Then
                ComboBox1.Items.Add(ProcessList(I).MainWindowTitle.ToString)
            End If


        Next
    Else
        ComboBox1.Items.Add("No windows found")
    End If
```

Comment: Try running as administrator

Comment: If you look at the processes in your development environment are they your app or visual studio?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not able to duplicate your problem, I have run your code in Visual Studio with no errors and from the executable with no errors. In looking up the error online, it wasn't to descriptive, suggesting that the process isn't accessable to the function. You can try adding some additional checks and as a last resort if you have Visual Studio Professional or higher you can [attach Visual Studio](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c6wf8e4z%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) to your executable and troubleshoot your error that way. Here is the code that I was using to test.

```
Public Class Form1

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim ProcessList() As Process = Process.GetProcesses
        If ProcessList.Count() >= 1 Then
            For Each p As Process In ProcessList
               If Not IsNothing(p) Then
                    If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(p.MainWindowTitle) Then
                        ComboBox1.Items.Add(p.MainWindowTitle.ToString)
                    End If
                End If
            Next
        Else
            ComboBox1.Items.Add("No windows found")
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
        Dim ProcessList() As Process = Process.GetProcesses
        If ProcessList.Count() >= 1 Then
            For Each p As Process In ProcessList
                If Not IsNothing(p) Then
                    ComboBox1.Items.Add(p.ProcessName)
                End If
            Next
        Else
            ComboBox1.Items.Add("No windows found")
        End If
    End Sub
End Class
```

Answer (score 0):

Change this line:

```
For I = 0 To UBound(ProcessList)
```

To:

```
For I = LBound(ProcessList) To UBound(ProcessList)
```

In VB, some arrays start at 1

Comment: Not since VB6, and any collection returned by System.Diagnostics.GetProcesses is going to be zero based

Comment: Sorry im not at home so i haven't tried it yet. Mark do you have any idea why it isn't working? Like i said it only happens with a compiled debug/release copy.

Comment: @user1632018 my first guess would be a permissions issue, try right clicking your exe and run as administrator

Comment: Hi mark, thanks for the reply. I will try it when i get home, the only issue is when i distribute my software to people having to get them run as an administrator might be a problem, if need be would i be able to code in the application that it automatically prompta the user to run as an administrator.

Comment: @user1632018 yes you would be able to, see if that actually is the issue, look at the GetProcesses docs see if it states what permissions if any are needed. I am traveling and on my iPhone I will look into it when I settle tonight